# Error de conexión en Python (MySQLdb._exceptions. OperationalError):

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Cordial saludo equipo, espero se encuentren bien necesito pedirles un favor con el siguiente requerimiento
Estoy desarrollando un CRUD como se ve en el siguiente enlace:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgCfZkR8wME&t=482s
Al insertar un registro que es el proceso  que se realiza hasta 25:00 del video me muestra el siguiente error:
MySQLdb._exceptions. OperationalError

MySQLdb._exceptions. OperationalError: (2002, "No se puede conectar al servidor MySQL en 'sql209.epizy.com' (138)")
El código que tengo es el siguiente:
Archivo App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST']= 'sql209.epizy.com'
app.config['MYSQL_USER']= 'epiz_31078268'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']= 'nps6dB2pQWm'
app.config['MYSQL_DB']= 'epiz_31078268_clasicoTK'

mysql= MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def Index():          # Cuando solo se ejecuta con 
  
 return render_template('index.html')
#@app.route('/add_contact')     # http://localhost:3000/add_contact
@app.route('/agregar_pais', methods=['POST'])
def agregar_pais():
  if request.method == 'POST':
     pais=request.form['pais']
     cur=mysql.connection.cursor()  
     cur.execute('INSERT INTO pais(pais) VALUES(%s)',
     (pais))
     mysql.connection.commit()

     return 'received'

@app.route('/editar_pais')  
def editar_pais():
  return 'editar pais'

@app.route('/eliminar_pais')  
def eliminar_pais():
  return 'eliminar pais' 



if __name__=='__main__':
  app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
```

Archivo index.html:

```
<form action="/agregar_pais" method="POST">
<label>Ingrese País <input type="text" name="pais" placeholder="pais"></label>
<button type="submit">
 Guardar_Pais
</button>
</form>
```

quede en 25:00 del mencionado video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgCfZkR8wME&t=482s)

Muchas gracias por su colaboración

Atentemente
Hernán Martínez

Comment: ¿Tenemos que mirar 25 minutos de video para entender el problema?

Comment: Pues si desea mirar todo el video pues sería bueno (dura aproximadamente hora y media), aunque mi problema se hace evidente en el minuto 25:00 al no poder conectarme bien a la base de datos con python

Comment: No sería nada bueno mirar ni 1 segundo. El error es claro: ¿tienes acceso a `sql209.epizy.com`? Al parecer, al seguir ciegamente el tutorial, has copiado la misma dirección de `host` usada allí. Mi impresión es: *el tutorial está muy mal hecho* o *no has prestado atención suficiente a la parte donde se establece el host*. Personalmente me decanto por ambas. Saludos

Comment: Si pruebas con `telnet sql209.epizy.com 3306` verás que el host no admite conexiones en la puerta 3306 (puerta por default para mySql)

Comment: Hola Candid Moe, muchas gracias probe con otro gestor de bases de datos libre como lo es db4free.net y no tuve ningun problema, gracias y saludos!.

Comment: Señor Mauricio Contreras, el inconveniente tan solo era el gestor de base de datos remoto y en el código remplazar cur.execute('INSERT INTO pais(pais) VALUES(%s)', (pais)) por [pais]), era tan solo eso, recomiendo ser noble, humilde y tratar a los demás con respeto,no es para que te pongas bravo, de todos modos saludos ;)